# Kendo controls - Encoding and why we need encoding?

Tags: c#, .net, security, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Controls for my application.

I have heard that MVC controls are automatically encoded by razor to add security.

How it will be a security risk if it is not encoded?

What about kendo controls?
Are they helper methods on wrapped from mvc controls?
will that be automatically encoded by Razor?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by encoded? The risk comes when you render something inside a widget that is created by the user. For example in the Grid this could be the values of the columns - in this case by default Kendo encodes all values rendered.

The same is true for every data-bound widget no matter if you are using the MVC wrappers or not.

More info available [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview).